# Extrusion or Keyboard shortcut Ctrl + B doesn't work correctly

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, faces

I want to make smooth edges on an object, but for some reason artifacts appear in the form of unnecessary edges, I ask for your help. I also attached the project file below in gogle Disk.
[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h_KX-J4KJ_ZLE1N2DcYCpAGIPb1nsxPg/view?usp=drive_link): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h_KX-J4KJ_ZLE1N2DcYCpAGIPb1nsxPg/view?usp=drive_link

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's called bevel, not extrusion. Extrusion is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices on your model.

In <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, select <kbd>All</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd>. You'll briefly see a message in the bottom status bar saying that 68 vertices have been removed. You can now select your edge again and use <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> to bevel it.

[image]

Although it isn't making much difference here, you should also apply the <kbd>Scale</kbd> to your object using <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> > <kbd>Scale</kbd> in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode before bevelling because it currently doesn't have uniform scale.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much